# Cypress detects cross origin error on test that does not leave main origin

Tags: cypress

I've been running into a problem with Cypress (currently v8.3.1 but this has been a constant for years) where my test detects a cross origin error on page load, but I am 99% certain that shouldn't apply.

The test logs into a web application and attempts to access a project.

```
cy.visit(webapp)                     //login page
cy.login(userCreds)                  //enter user cred and access main page
cy.get(projectAcccessButton).click() //access project from main
```

As the project page loads, Cypress throws the cross origin error below. I've been using the `"chromeWebSecurity": false` workaround, but it does not apply to Firefox. Firefox test coverage is on the "2022 To Do" list, so I am turning to Stack for answers - I hope.

What I want to do: Access the project page without issue.

What has been happening: cross origin error on page load

> Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object

I mentioned that the cross origin error likely shouldn't apply because when I modify the test to access the project page via `cy.visit()`, Cypress does not throw an error.

```
cy.visit(webapp)                     //login page
cy.login(userCreds)                  //enter user cred and access main page
cy.visit(projectPage)                //access project via url
```

This leads me to believe something is happening on the button click that is somehow triggering the cross origin error. Is it possible that the button attribute `onclick="window.location.href='/projectManager/123456789'"` is somehow being interpreted as leaving the main origin?

If this error is related to the `window.location.href`, how can I resolve this so Cypress doesn't detect an error when running in Firefox?

Full Error Message:

[image: CypressError]